# Issue with reproducibility across different sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to make a script reproducible but having some issue. The code is in Tensorflow 2.x and doesn't use keras API. It has many layers build with tf.compat. The model is created and trained with a function `get_model()`

```
os.environ['tf_deterministic_ops'] = "2"
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "2"
random.seed(2)
np.random.seed(2)
tf.random.set_seed(2)
for i in range(5):
    get_model()
```

So, I am training the same model 5 times above, and the results are same every time. But When I run the following script 5 times, the results are different. Am I doing something wrong? Any help will be great. Thanks!

```
os.environ['tf_deterministic_ops'] = "2"
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "2"
random.seed(2)
np.random.seed(2)
tf.random.set_seed(2)
get_model()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say everything behaves normally:
Setting a random-seed always produces the same sequence of random variables, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
# set seed
np.random.seed(2)

for i in range(5):
    print(np.random.randint(10))     # prints:  8, 8, 6, 2, 8

for i in range(5):
    np.random.seed(2)
    print(np.random.randint(10))     # prints:  8, 8, 8, 8, 8
```

So running your second script five times produces the same model each time because you are setting the seed to 2 with each execution. Iterating the for loop in your first script produces models that correspond to the variables from first five outputs with `seed=2`. Using my code example: Your second script would always create model '8', your first script creates models '8', '8', '6', '2', and '8'.